# Create textbox at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox, runtime

with this code I can create at runtime textbox components:

```
 List<TextBox> customTextBox = new List<TextBox>();

 foreach (string ValutaCustomScelta in Properties.Settings.Default.ValuteCustom)
     {
       TextBox textbox = new TextBox();
       textbox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(295, 117 + customTextBox.Count * 26);       textbox.BackColor = Color.Black;
       textbox.ForeColor = Color.Lime;
       textbox.Parent = tabPage2;
       textbox.Name = "textbox_" + SelectValute;
       textbox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(80, 21);

       customTextBox.Add(textbox);
       tabPage2.Controls.Add(textbox);
       tabPage2.Controls.SetChildIndex(textbox, 0);
      }
```

This code is placed in form 2, but I need the that textboxes are created to be in form1. I dont know which instruction is needed to add it in this code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: ..can you not simply move this code into your other form?

Comment: I cant because this code is associate with control placed in form2

Comment: You have to give us more information on what you are trying to do, otherwise the answer will simply be "write the same code in form 1"...

Comment: ok, I need create runtime textboxes in form1, clicking a button placed in form2. This is my problem.

Comment: Is Form1 connected with Form2 somehow? What's the flow? Is Form1 a form that is displayed and modified after actions on Form2 or is Form2 a child of Form1 maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

You need to keep a reference to `Form1` in `Form2`. For example:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form {
    private Form1 _form1;

    public Form2(Form1 form) {
        _form1 = form;
    }
}
```

Then you can use this in `Form2`:

```
_form1.Controls.Add(textbox);
_form1.Controls.SetChildIndex(textbox, 0);
```

You'll need to create `Form2` like this (from `Form1`):

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2(this);
```

Comment: I cant move the code in  form1, because this code has to run clicking button placed in form 2

Comment: @vincenzolopalo You can't add an event to Form2 and handle it in Form1?